# Python 3 flask cairo package wrong architecture on Apple M1 silicon

Tags: python, cairo, macports, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm trying to run a project on my new MacBook Pro M1

The python "Flask" project uses **md2pdf** that depends on **cairo**

I've got an error implementing the cairographics package

that I installed using sudo port install cairo

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/intent_gatherer", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('intent-gatherer', 'console_scripts', 'intent_gatherer')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2862, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2462, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2468, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Users/robenalam/Documents/deeplink/chatbotstrap/gatherer_backend/intent_gatherer/manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    from intent_gatherer.app import create_app
  File "/Users/robenalam/Documents/deeplink/chatbotstrap/gatherer_backend/intent_gatherer/app.py", line 8, in <module>
    from intent_gatherer import auth, api
  File "/Users/robenalam/Documents/deeplink/chatbotstrap/gatherer_backend/intent_gatherer/api/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/robenalam/Documents/deeplink/chatbotstrap/gatherer_backend/intent_gatherer/api/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from intent_gatherer.api.resources import (
  File "/Users/robenalam/Documents/deeplink/chatbotstrap/gatherer_backend/intent_gatherer/api/resources/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from .card import (
  File "/Users/robenalam/Documents/deeplink/chatbotstrap/gatherer_backend/intent_gatherer/api/resources/card.py", line 20, in <module>
    from md2pdf.core import md2pdf
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/md2pdf/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from md2pdf.core import md2pdf  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/md2pdf/core.py", line 5, in <module>
    from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 469, in <module>
    from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa isort:skip
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/weasyprint/css/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import computed_values, counters, media_queries
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/weasyprint/css/computed_values.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .. import text
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/weasyprint/text.py", line 11, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 45, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library '/opt/local/lib/libcairo.dylib': dlopen(/opt/local/lib/libcairo.dylib, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/lib/libcairo.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /opt/local/lib/libcairo.2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': dlopen(libcairo.so.2, 2): image not found
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': dlopen(libcairo.2.dylib, 2): image not found
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': dlopen(libcairo-2.dll, 2): image not found
```

I've tried to install cairo using brew but the the package for some reason wasn't detected by python.

Comment: The answer to your question will depend on the architecture for which libcairo.dylib was installed. Run `lipo -info /opt/local/lib/libcairo.dylib` to find out. If it's x86_64, that's wrong and we need to figure out why; MacPorts should have installed it arm64. If it's already arm64, then you need to figure out why python and/or flask isn't building for arm64. MacPorts doesn't install python in /Library/Frameworks, so whatever python you have there came from somewhere else. If you had used MacPorts python (e.g. `sudo port install python38`) it should have worked.

Comment: Don't install both MacPorts and Homebrew. They will interfere with one another and cause confusing problems that nobody will want to help diagnose. Pick one and uninstall the other and anything you had installed with it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **Application** folder -> Right click on **Terminal** App -> **Get Info**

Tick **Open with Rosetta** option.

Try now.

Comment: Opening your terminal with Rosetta 2 will launch it and its subprocesses including the shell as x86_64. I believe Homebrew was recommending this when they were not ready to run natively on Apple Silicon; that may still be the case.

MacPorts, on the other hand, was ready for Apple Silicon before those products shipped, and launching the terminal and shell in x86_64 will definitely confuse MacPorts, so please do not do that if you are using MacPorts.